# How to translate Fortran move_alloc intrinsic in OpenACC kernel?

Tags: fortran, openacc

I'm working on porting a Fortran code on GPU with OpenACC directives. The data structures contain allocatable arrays. When arrays are resized

- a new array (we can call it `tmp`) is allocated with the new size
- this new array `tmp` is filled with the content of the allocatable array, attribute of the data structure (with additional 0 if required)
- then move_array intrinsic is used to replace the allocatable in the structure by this new resized array `tmp` (so no additional copy).
  If this is efficient in the host code I do not understand how to do this in a Kernel where my data structure and its allocatable are yet offloaded and my new array `tmp` is created on the GPU.

I search in the OpenACC documentation but it does not look like an `attach` directive as after the `move_array` intrinsic call the `tmp` variable is in deallocated state. So I've no idea how to translate this in a kernel.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. We do not sign our posts here and do not add any "Thanks"or similar, the post is signed automatically with your username and date. I think it will be best to illustrate the question with some code. See also [ask].